# edit comma seperated fields and grep specific field bigger than my condition

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

Input:

```
10,6-2021,863
11,1-2017,990
12,012020,000
13,1-2021,000
```

Output:

```
10,06/2021,863
12,01/2020,000
13,01/2021,000
```

in the input data, the field number 2 is date, so i would like to display date > `1-2017` or `012017` and print it with `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved By

```
gawk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} {patsplit($2,a,/[0-9][0-9]?/); $2 = sprintf("%02d/%d%d", a[1], a[2], a[3])} 1' file
```

Then

```
awk -F '[,/]' '($3 == 2017 && $2 >= 01) || $3 > 2017' file
```